# Existence of continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with some properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Does there exist exist a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with following properties:

- $f$ not surjective
- for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\vert x \vert \to \infty $  we have $\frac{\langle f(x), x \rangle}{\vert x \vert} \to \infty$
- $\langle f(x), x \rangle \neq 0$ for all $x \neq 0$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried answering the question for small $n$?

Comment: For $n=1$ that's equivalent to find an unbounded nonwhere zero continuous function $f: R \to R$. eg the exp function. For $n=2$ maybe the task becomes now to find two functions $_1$ and $f_2$ as in case $n=1$ with additional property that these preserve the sign of the arguments $i$-th value. That looks harder. Then set $f(x_1,x_2)= (f_1(x_1), f_2(x_2))$. Then $\rangle f(x_1,x_2), (x_1,x_2) \langle =f_1(x_1) \cdot x_1+f_1(x_1) \cdot x_1 >0$ if  $x_1,x_2 \neq 0$ and for bigger $n$ this should work inductively assuming we can find $f$ with desired properties in dimenson $1$ which preserves sign.

Comment: $\exp$ is not an example since $xe^x/|x| \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following theorem is known:

If $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\frac{\langle f(x),x\rangle}{|x|} \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$, then $f$ is surjective.

I know the following proof using Brouwer's degree:

Fix any $y \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the homotopy
$$
h(t,x)=tx+(1-t)f(x) \quad (t \in [0,1], x \in \overline{B_r(0)}),
$$
with $B_r(0)$ the open ball with center $0$ and radius $r >0$. For $r  > |y|$
sufficiently large we have for each $x$ with $|x|=r$ and $t \in [0,1]$ that
$$
\langle h(t,x)-y,x\rangle \ge r \left(tr+(1-t)\frac{\langle f(x),x\rangle}{|x|}-|y|\right) > 0,
$$
hence $y \notin h(t,\partial B_r(0))$ $(t \in [0,1])$. Thus $d(f,B_r(0),y)= d(id,B_r(0) ,y)=1$,
that is $f(x)=y$ has a solution in $B_r(0)$.

Comment: why $d(f ,B_r(0),y)= d(id,B_r(0) ,y)=1$? as a side note, does the notation  $d(f ,B_r(0),y)$ mean $ \min d(a,y) \vert a \in f(B_r(0) $ ?

Comment: Since $r>|y|$ we have $y \in B_r(0)$, hence $d(id,B_r(0),y)=1$. The equation $d(f , B_r(0),y)=d(id , B_r(0),y)$ comes form the homotopy since $h(0,\cdot)=f$ and $h(1,\cdot)=id$. The symbol $d$ is not a distance, it is the Brouwer degree, often also denoted as $deg$ instead of $d$. It is a rather deep tool, I am not sure  if there is a more elementary proof of this result. I know this result form the book of Deimling: Nonlinear functional analysis, Springer (1985); Theorem 3.3